# How use key_name from ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

sorry for my bad english.
I make app in c with `ncurses-5.9` lib. In docs for lib ( ncurses-5.9/doc/html/man/curs_util.3x.html )  I found what function `key_name` defined in curses.h, but if I include
curses.h, I still get error  `key_name` was not declared in this scope.

What i need to do for to use key_name function?

Comment: Please post exact error compiler shows. also give the command you use to compile.

Comment: ex.c: In function ‘main’: 
ex.c:8:16: 
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] 
/tmp/ccNpFkix.o: In function main': ex.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to key_name' collect2: ld returned 1 ex
</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include `<ncurses.h>` as well.

And be sure that it is properly installed on your distro, and that you link it correctly at compilation.

If you still have trouble, check where the files are.

```
$sudo updatedb
$locate curses.h
$locate ncurses.h
```

Edit:

From the error you pasted, it shows that it's not a problem of header inclusion. LD (the linker) can't find the symbol associated to key_name. Which means that your are not compiling with the correct libray (maybe path issues) or that you need an extra one, or that key_name does'nt exist in the version you are trying to use.

And I think you are not passing the good parameter in the function, you are using "wint_t" instead of "wchar_t", It might be why it can't find the function.

And also try -lcurses in addition

Comment: I include curses.h and ncurses.h, i use -lncurses but still get same error

Comment: Could you paste the compiler output please.

Comment: Src example
<pre>
#include <curses.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  wint_t c = '\n';
  char *name = key_name(c);
  printf("Char name : %s\n",name); 
  return 0;
}
</pre>
Compile 
`gcc ex.c -lncurses`

Err:
ex.c: In function ‘main’:
ex.c:8:16: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/tmp/ccNpFkix.o: In function `main':
ex.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `key_name'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It's not a problem of headers, it's a problem of linking. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

For use key_name we must use libncursesw5-dev instead of libncurses5-dev.